# Can't query an edge_ngram field in _all

Tags: elasticsearch

So I'm setting up an index and I'd like to have a single search that would do a partial-word `edge_ngram` search for one field and a more normal search of the rest of the fields. From what I understand this should be easy to do by just matching on `_all`. However I just can't seem to make it work.

I have been able to get the desired results from a `bool` query that searches `_all` and the specific ngram field separately but that seems hackey and I'm guessing there's just something simple that I'm missing.

Here is just a minimal example to show what I'm doing and how it's not working for me.

Here is the index setup:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index?pretty=true" -d'
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "edge_ngram_filter": {
               "type": "edge_ngram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "edge_ngram_filter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "text_field": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
               "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

And add a simple document:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/doc/1?pretty=true" -d'
{
    "text_field": "Hello, World!"
}'
```

_all partial search doesn't work. It returns an empty result.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/_search?pretty=true" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "_all": "hell"
        }
    }
}'
```

_all whole word search works though

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/_search?pretty=true" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "_all": "hello"
        }
    }
}'
```

And a partial search on the specific field works

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/_search?pretty=true" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "text_field": "hell"
        }
    }
}'
```

The term vector looks fine too

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test_index/doc/1/_termvector?fields=text_field&pretty=true"
```

I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are some details about my environment.

- Elasticsearch version: `Version: 2.3.3, Build: 218bdf1/2016-05-17T15:40:04Z, JVM: 1.8.0_92`
- Linux OS: Arch Linux
- Kernel version: `4.4.3-1-custom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_all` field combines the original values of all fields as a string, not the terms produced for each field. So in your case, it doesn't contain the terms produced by the `edge_ngram_analyzer`, just the text from the `text_field` field. It's just like any other text field, you can specify analyzers for it, etc. In your example, it's using the default analyzer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you happen to know how I could change the analyzer for the `_all` field? When I try to add it to mappings I get `Failed to parse mapping [doc]: Field [_all] is defined twice in [doc]`.

Comment: Nevermind. I think I figured it out by adding this: `{mappings: {doc: {_all: {analyzer: "edge_ngram_analyzer"}}}}`

Comment: Yup, that's the way. The _all mapping needs to be under the type, not  under the properties root.